# which one is better to use for scholarship application: personal or institutional email?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, funding

should I use my university domain email **to show the admission committee** that I am an academic staff, or my personal email for scholarship application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use your institutional email to contact potential supervisors if it is appropriate. In my opinion, it looks more *professional*, and some professors I know only reply to institutional emails. It has nothing to do with your current employment status.

However, if you formally apply through a university portal, I don't think there is anyone bothering checking your email address. Possibly, all they can see about you is just the applicant ID/username.

Comment: though I will look forward other opinions, it is best answer